# What's the point of CachingActivityMapper?

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt-activities, gwt-places

The `CachingActivityMapper` will return the same activity instance if asked for the same `Place` twice or more. However, `PlaceController` will not fire a `PlaceChangeRequestEvent` (and ultimately no `PlaceChangeEvent`) if I was to `goTo(...)` a place that equals the current one. As a result, the `ActivityManager` listening to those events will not do anything, that is, it won't even ask the `CachingActivityMapper` for an activity in this case.

So, I don't really see the point of `CachingActivityMapper`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CachingActivityMapper` is of little (to no) use when used alone. It's really meant to be between something like a [`FilteredActivityMapper`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/FilteredActivityMapper.html) and your `ActivityMapper`.

The original usecase was master-detail; for example, for a mail app, with 2 `ActivityManager`s, one for the list of mails (master) and the other for a specific message (detail), and we could imagine a third one with a menu or treeview; let's concentrate on the *master*:

1. The current place is `MailBox("inbox")`

   1. the `FilteredActivityMapper` passes the place as-is to the underlying `CachingActivityMapper`
   2. the actual `ActivityMapper` returns an activity for the list of mails in the "inbox"
2. the user clicks on a mail in the list, *going to* a new place `Message(box="inbox", id="123")`

   1. the `FilteredActivityMapper` transforms the place to `MailBox("inbox")`
   2. the `CachingActivityMapper` returns the cached activity, without actually calling the wrapped `ActivityMapper`; so the `ActivityManager` won't stop and start the activity, or touch the `HasOneWidget` it's managing.

There can be variants, for example, the *detail* mapper could cache the last *Message* place it seen (where that *Message* place wouldn't contain the "mail box" information, i.e. `Message("123")`), and when it receives a *MailBox* place, it would pass the *Message* place to the underlying `CachingActivityMapper`, which would return the cached activity; that would allow the *master* to change to a new mail box while still displaying the same message in the *detail* panel (GMail with split display behaves more or less like this).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Thomas!

Comment: I lost the count of how many times your answers helped me. Thank you again. My screen flickered every time upon a place switch, because my HeaderView, ContentView, FooterView etc. were attached to MainView, which in turn had to be detached/attached every single time. Regardless how fast the computer running the app was, flickering was noticeable anyway. By filtering places I finally managed to solve this issue.